# IOS auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, interface-builder

having trouble with my first app login screen...
it looks good on iphone 8 screen size

[image: on iphone 8]

but when the screen is smaller - the images go off screen.

[image: iphone se]

i use auto-layout with interface builder.

tried playing around with the constraints:
 - spacing less or equal with high priority 
 - use a stack view
 - autoshrink on the text label
 - compression resistance

so far couldn't get the right set of constraints for it to work.

anyone?

Update following the comments:

these are my constraints:
[image]
and autoshrink on the label with "minimum font scale"

i want the the images will get closer to the text, and the text to shrink so they all will be shown in one line.

Comment: design in small screen and use auto-resizing instead of constraints.

Comment: Show your constraints

Comment: Show us your constraints then only we can help you out :)

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: Very simply, on the **UILabel** set the "number of lines" to **zero**, which means it will break and take as many lines as necessary.

Comment: @Fattie thank you for your comment, but i don't want the lines to break...

Comment: @Paulw11
thank you for your comments.
Updated my question with my constraints...

Comment: @RizwanAhmed thank you for your comment. Updated my question with my constraints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor the images to the edges, then it will shrink the font size as long as you have set `Autoshrink`. Connect as the image below.

Basically, it is connected like this
`|<-->image<-->label<-->image<-->|`
Then set them images to fixed sizes, and let the label size itself.
You also need to position them on the Y axis.

[image]

Comment: thank you, it does work.
but now i think the images should shrink too in proportion to the text....
and i'm only in the first screen. fun fun fun :)

Comment: Great! One solution is to set the images heights to be proportional to the labels height, then lock the images widths to their heights with aspect ratio constraints. To set a proportional constraint you do (in this case) a regular height of image equals height of label, then set the constraints multiplier to `1:2` or `25:30` or whatever ratio you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with this

[image]

The following result in iPhone 5s

[image]

and 8 plus

[image]

Comment: set label line number 1